# $f(x)f(1/x)=f(x)+f(1/x)$

Tags: analysis, functions, polynomials, functional-equations

Find a function $f(x)$ such that:

$$f(x)f(1/x)=f(x)+f(1/x)$$

with $f(4)=65$.

I have tried to let $f(x)$ be a general polynomial:
$$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots a_nx^n$$

which leaves $f(1/x)$ as:

$$a_0+a_1{1\over x}+a_2{1\over x^2}+\ldots + a_n{1\over x^n}$$

On comparing the coefficients of both sides, we see that:

$$2a_0=(a_0)^2+(a_1)^2+(a_2)^2+\ldots+(a_n)^2$$

And

$$a_1=(a_0a_1)+(a_1a_2)+ \ldots +(a_{n-1}a_n)$$

I don't know how to proceed further. I know I need to compare coefficients and come to a conclusion based on their values, but I don't see what to do next.

Comment: [See this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to write math formulas on this site.

Comment: Is $f$ defined at $0$?

Comment: why do you let be $f(x)$ a polynomial?

Comment: The answer is actually $f(x) = x^(3) +1$

Comment: (My friend used hit and trial to find it, but we require a solid proof)

Comment: yes it's defined @gary

Comment: @tennis pro:How do you define $f(0)f(1/0)$?

Comment: I let $f(x)$ be a polynomial because the question's answer is in the form of a polynomial.

Comment: According to another source, the function is also always equal to $(+or-)x^n +1$

Comment: But $4^n+1 >65$ for $n>3$

Comment: Oops, then no. Sorry, I was thinking about $f(x)$. But $f(1/x)$ isn't defined at

Comment: Wouldn't n be equal to 3? Then we'd get x^3. And 4^3 =64. Then on adding 1, we'd get 65.

Comment: As in juantheron's solution: whenever you have $XY = X + Y$ consider rewriting it as $XY - X - Y + 1 = 1$ which then factorises into $(X-1)(Y-1) = 1$, which is often easier to deal with.

Comment: I don't think that $f(x)$ here is a polynomial or a function at all. If $x=1$ is substituted here then, we get $f(1)^2 = 2f(1)$, then $f(1)= 0$ or $2$. This fails the vertical line test and hence neither is it a polynomial nor a function....

Comment: @rash $f(1) = 0$ **OR** $2$ is different from $f(1) = 0$ **and** $2$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As other answers show, there is a large class of solutions to your functional equation if one does not restrict $f$ more. As per your request, we shall try the restriction that $f$ should be a polynomal.

Two polynomial solutions jump into our eyes, namely the zero polynomial $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=2$. Neither of these has $f(4)=65$, though.

If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n>0$, say $$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots +a_nx^n$$ with $a_n\ne 0$, then $\hat f(x) = x^nf(1/x)$ is also a polynomial, namely
$$ \hat f(x)=x^nf(1/x)=a_n+a_{n-1}x+\ldots+a_0x^n.$$
Observe that $a_0$ could be $0$, so possibly $\deg\hat f<n$.
The functional equation becomes after multiplication with $x^n$
$$ f(x)\hat f(x)=x^nf(x)+\hat f(x)$$
or
$$\tag1 f(x)\cdot(\hat f(x)-x^n)=\hat f(x).$$
But if we multiply the degree $n$ polynomial $f(x)$ with the polynomial $\hat f(x)-x^n$ and obtain the polynomial $\hat f(x)$ that has degree $\le n$, we conclude that $\hat f(x)-x^n$ must be a constant. This implies that $a_0=1$ and $a_1=\ldots=a_{n-1}=0$, so $f(x)=a_nx^n+1$ and $(1)$ simplifies to
$$ (a_nx^n+1)\cdot a_n = x^n+a_n$$
This allows only $a_n=\pm1$. To meet the constraint $f(4)=65$, we need $\pm 4^n=65-1$, so the positive sign and exponent $3$. We finally conclude that
$${f(x)=x^3+1}. $$

Comment: I fail to understand why $a_n$ could be equal to -1. Could you explain? I feel it can only be +1.

Comment: look at the second last equation. open up the brackets to see why

Answer (score 19):

Given: $\displaystyle f(x)+f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = f(x)\cdot f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\tag 1$

Now we can write $(1)$ as $$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-1}\tag 2$$

Now again we can write $(1)$ as $$\displaystyle f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{f(x)}{f(x)-1}\tag 3$$

Now multiplying these two equations, we get $\displaystyle \left[f(x)-1\right]\cdot \left[f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-1\right]=1$

Let $f(x)-1 = g(x)$. Then, $$f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-1 = g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

So the equation gets converted into: $$\displaystyle g(x)\cdot g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) =1$$

Now if $g(x)$ is a polynomial, then $g(x) = \pm x^n$. So $f(x) = 1\pm x^n$.

We are given that $f(4) = 65$. So, $$f(x)=1+x^n$$ On putting $x=4$, we get $n=3$.

Thus, we get, $$f(x)=1+x^3$$

Comment: Suppose $f(x)$ is not a polynomial, then can more functions be concluded from $g(x).g(1/x)=1$?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that $f$ is nonzero, we can rewrite this equation as: $$\frac{1}{f(x)} + \frac{1}{f(1/x)} = 1$$

Making the substitution $g(y) = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{f(e^y)}$, we get the functional equation $g(y) + g(-y) = 0$, which simply says that $g$ is odd.

This equation can be solved, with the initial condition, by setting $g(y) = cy$ for a suitable constant $c$.

Answer (score 4):

I just observed that a non polynomial solution $$\frac{\pi}{2\tan^{-1}(x)}$$ also exists . How can we find other non polynomial solutions ?

Comment: Does $f(4)=65$?

Comment: @Samyak But i think it fails for $x<0$.

Answer (score 4):

The equation is equivalent to
$$
\frac1{f(x)}+\frac1{f(1/x)}=1
$$
so we can set
$$
f(x)=\frac1{\frac12-\frac{63\,g(\log(x))}{130\,g(\log(4))}}
$$
where $g(x)$ is any odd function.

---

$g(x)=\tanh(2x)$ gives
$$
f(x)=\frac{11050\left(1+x^4\right)}{10922+128x^4}
$$
Not a polynomial, but at least a rational function.

---

$g(x)=\tanh\left(\frac32x\right)$ gives
$$
f(x)=1+x^3
$$
which is the answer given by juantheron.

Answer (score 3):

Note that plugging in $x=1$, we obtain
$$f(1)^2 = 2f(1) \implies f(1) = 0 \text{ or }2$$
Similarly, plugging in $x=-1$, we obtain
$$f(-1) = 0 \text{ or }2$$
We have
$$f(1/x)(f(x) - 1) = f(x) \implies f(1/x) = \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)-1}$$
Hence, for $\vert x \vert > 1$ define $f(x) = g(x)$ such that $g(x) \neq 1$ for all $\vert x \vert >1$. Then define
$$f(1/x) = \dfrac{g(x)}{g(x)-1}$$
Hence, there exists a wide class of possible functions given by
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 \text{ or }2& x = \pm1\\
g(x) & \vert x \vert > 1 \text{ such that }g(x) \neq 1\\
\dfrac{g(1/x)}{g(1/x)-1} & \vert x \vert < 1 \text{ and }x \neq 0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last part of your answer. Exactly how are you defining $g(x)$

Comment: @tennispro1213 $g$ can be any function.

Comment: Okay, so basically $g$ is the same thing as $f$ and it just makes $f(x)$ easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @user17762's answer, suppose $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ where $a_n\ne 0$ and $n\ge 1$, then $f=g$ for $|x|>1$, we have for $|x|<1$,

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^{-i}}{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^{-i}-1}=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^{n-i}}{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^{n-i}-x^n}$$

For RHS to be a polynomial you have $a_0=1$ or $a_0\ne 1$ and $a_i=0$ for $i>0$ (which contradicts $a_n\ne 0$). Now the numerator has highest power $n$ and so does LHS, so the denominator has to be constant, i.e. $a_i=0$ for $0<i<n$, now $f(x)=c x^n+1$ for some $c\ne 0$. Putting this back in you have $c=\pm 1$. Solving this for $x=4$ gives your result.